# PyQT Proper GUI settings management?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I have two windows - **main** and **conf**. **Main** stores geometry and quick-settings, **Conf** - contains all kinds of configuration options.

Does anybody knows proper way to store config options for both windows in a same ini file, and read it from both windows ?

Comment: [QSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate python class for each window, and then create an instance from one window inside the other. this way you can access both windows from the original window.

for example in your main window you can have something like this

```
instance = confWindow()
instance.saveConfig.connect(self.saveConf)
```